# Doesn't continuously read messages from IBM MQ Queue

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

When i have 2000 messages in an import queue, when i read it through get like this

```
MQQueue mqQueue = null; 
MQQueueManager mqQMgr=null;  
try
{
  //Create connection to queue manager
   mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("Queue Manager name", properties);
  //Access the queue
    mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(QueueName, MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE);
   for(int i=1;i<2000;i++)
  {
    //read the messages
    mqMsg=new MQMessage();
    mqQueue.Get(mqMsg);
  }
}
catch(MQException mqe)
{  
  //If no messages in the queue , break. (if not, catch any error)
}
finally
{
     mqQueue.Close(); //Close the MQ Queue
     mqQMgr.Disconnect(); //Disconnect the MQ Manager
}
```

The manager processes randomly everytime when i read, for example first 800 messages and then it throws back

> "MQRC_HANDLE_NOT_AVAILABLE" (comp code:2 , reason code:2017).

Am I not closing the queue/manager in the above piece of code ? Please share your thoughts, so that, all the messages can be processed. I am using 7.5 MQ client via MQ.net classes. The log file contains this below info.

> AMQ9051: WebSphere MQ could not find the security policy definition.
>   Compcode 2 : reason 2017 EXPLANATION: The security policy definition
>   is not defined. ACTION: Security policy definition must be defined
>   before this action.

Comment: Please post the entry from the QMgr's `AMQERR01.LOG` error log when this happens.  Also, check the global `AMQERR01.LOG` error log to see if there's anything there, or whether any FDC files get cut.

Comment: T.Rob - I see its in the QManager, do you know the location/path?

Comment: Your snippet does not show queue being opened.

Comment: Shashi - I didn't add that line earlier, but i actually have it in my code piece, have edited now the above snippet.

Comment: The 2017 error can occur if maximum number of MQ handles an application can open has been reached. By default it is set to 256 and can be modified alter MAXHANDS queue manager attribute. It is surprising as your code opens queue only once. Ar there are any other threads in the application that are opening queues?

Comment: Thanks, this is the only get method, that reads and processes the messages back to send/put method, please check and let me know your suggestions in the code.

Comment: AMQERRO1.LOG can be found under "errors" folder under MQ install folder and per queue manager logs can be found under <MQ install>\qmgrs\<qmname>\errors folder.

Comment: Any idea on this, I checked that error log, it says

ACTION:
Security policy definition must be defined before this action. 
4/11/2013 15:12:42 - 
                     
AMQ9051: WebSphere MQ could not find the security policy definition. Compcode 2
: reason 2017

EXPLANATION:
The security policy definition is not defined.
ACTION:

Security policy definition must be defined before this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your sample code snippet and works fine for me. I don't see 2017 error.

The entry in error log may have a relation to your problem. Have you set security policy for the queue and expecting signed/signed&encrypted messages to be put/get to/from queue? It may be worth opening a ticket/PMR with IBM.

Comment: I downloaded from ibm site the 7.5 MQ client. I am not putting/getting any encrypted messages to/from the queue. Its odd that, it processes some(for example 800 messages out of 2000) and then stops processing.